# if BadWords in msg: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python, string, split, typeerror

So i have an BadWords.txt file, that i have embedded in the BW_Filter.py

here is the BW_Filter.py code:

```
with open('BadWords.txt') as f: 
  words = f.read()
  BadWords = words.split()

def on_message():
  msg = input("Type: ")
  if BadWords in msg:
    print("Dont use that word!")

  elif BadWords not in msg:
    print("Message send!")

on_message()
```

if i now type a sentence with a BadWord from the BadWord.txt file, or just the BadWord in single without other words, than it gives me an error like this:

if BadWords in msg: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

(In my other question on stackoverflow(that no one had answer correctly, or understandful)there it works, but just with the first word of the BadWords.txt file that contains the BadWords)

then i changed some things and now the code looks like so:

```
with open('BadWords.txt') as f:
  words = f.read()
  BadWords = words.split()

def on_message():
  msg = input("Type: ")
  if BadWords.__contains__(msg):
    print("Dont use that word!")

  else:
    print("Message send!")

on_message()
```

in this code is the problem that i cannot write sentences with the BadWords, but if i type a BadWord single without other words it works.

I have asked a question before with a similar problem, but now i changed some things, and ask again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if BadWords in msg:
```

do:

```
if any(word in msg for word in BadWords):
```

You aren't allowed to do `list in str` (as the error message indicates), but using `any` allows you to easily loop through each item in the list and do individual `str in str` checks, with a `True` result if `any` of those checks returns `True`.

Comment: Thank really much! It Works perfect!